# how to call button click event on click of slice of piechart using highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to call button click event on click of piechart slice. The button click event is there in code behind page. The button is of type Link Button and href is generating dynamically on it like this

```js
                  point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function (event) {
                  
$("#m_p1_ButtonApplyFilter").trigger();              
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

```html
<a id="m_p1_ButtonApplyFilter" class="genericButton" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("m$p1$ButtonApplyFilter", "", true, "MyAnalysis", "", false, true))'>Apply Filters</a>
```

And i am calling the button event from my piechart slice that i have writen in the fiddle but unable to call button click event. Kindly suggest me how to call the button event from piechart.I am using highchart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
point: {
  events: {
    click: function (event) {
            functionForClick(this.name)
    }
  }
}
.......
.......

function functionForClick(obj){
document.getElementById(obj).click();
   }
```

```html
 <button id="Microsoft Internet Explorer" onclick="alert('Microsoft Internet Explorer was clicked')">Microsoft Internet Explorer
</button>
```

You can add function `functionForClick(this.id);` inside the `events:{...}`.This will call function and click the respective button

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vy9xzbnv/1/)